# Adding asp.net to html page

Tags: html, asp.net, addition

First of all thanks for reading my question...

I want to put code 2 into code 1... Anyone please help me.

code 1 is normal HTML page.

```
code 1:

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        //I want to add code 2 here..
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



code 2:

if(System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString()+"Frame.xml"))
{
   //something
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use ASP controls on your HTML page? For example: <asp:Literal> ?

Comment: whether it is possible to add code 2 into code 1??? @Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it

```
<%@ Page Title="YourPage" Language="C#" %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <% 
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString()+"Frame.xml")) {

        }
        %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: also, rename your file to yourfile.aspx! :)

Comment: Thanks @Lars Anundskas. But I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error in    if(System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString()+"Frame.xml"))

Comment: Does the key DBCache exist in your appSettings ?

Comment: It is in remotely @Lars Anundskas

Comment: please explain, "in remotely" ?

Comment: I want to read from .xml file. this .xml file is in another(remote) computer.

Comment: So what is the value of your DBCache appsetting entry?

Comment: Oh... sorry now only I see my web.config file. I forget to add DBCache in appsettings. Now Its working. thanks for your valuable response @Lars Anundskås

Comment: np, please mark as answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've used ASP.NET pages. Try this:

```
<script runat="server">
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString()+"Frame.xml")) {
        myLiteral.Text="Welcome to ASP.NET!!";
    }
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Literal id="myLiteral" runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like following:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
             <% if(your condition)
               {%>

              <% } %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Irfan TahirKheli. But I am getting the code2 in my output of html page...